# How many right triangles can you find?

Tags: code-golf, math, number

## Challenge

You will be given an input represented by `x`, which is a string containing at least 3 characters. It will consist only of the standard numeric characters, 0 through 9. Your job is to find and output how many right triangles can be formed with the given numbers.

## Rules

- Numbers must be kept in the order they were given in. No mixing them up!
- The numbers for each right triangle must be consecutive.
- The order of numbers has to be `a` first, `b` second, and `c` third, and must satisfy the formula `a² + b² = c²`. `a` can be greater than or less than `b`, as long as it satisfies the formula.
- Decimal points may be added between any numbers.
- Decimals require one or more numbers to be placed before them, e.g. `.5` cannot be used as a number but `0.5` and `12.5` can.
- Decimals with at least 4 digits after the decimal point truncated to the third digit, e.g. `1.2345` would truncated to `1.234` and `1.9999` would be truncated to `1.999`.
- Numbers can be used more than once in 2 or more different triangles, but cannot be used multiple times in the same triangle.
- Multiple representations of the same value can count multiple times.
- Repeating zeros are allowed, e.g. `000.5` counts as a number.
- *All* possible combinations must be taken into account for your program to be valid.

## Example Inputs and Outputs

Input: 345
Output: 1
This can be split into `3`, `4`, and `5`, which, of course, form a right triangle.

Input: 534
Output: 0
While this does include the necessary numbers to form a right triangle, they are not in the correct order. It has to follow the formula `a² + b² = c²`, but in this case it follows `c² = a² + b²`. The order of numbers cannot be changed from the original input, so in this case no right triangles can be formed.

Input: 3415
Output: 0
This does contain a `3`, `4`, and a `5`, which can form a right triangle, but they are not consecutive; there is a `1` splitting the `5` from the `3` and `4`.

Input: 5567507
Output: 1
Because decimals can be added anywhere, it can be changed to `55.67.507`, which allows splitting it into `5`, `5.6`, and `7.507` to form a right triangle. Remember that decimals are truncated to the third digit after the decimal point, which is how we get `7.507`.

Input: 345567507
Output: 2
The first right triangle is formed by `3`, `4`, and `5`. The second one is formed by `5567507` (read the previous example for explanation). Numbers can be used more than once, so the first `5` was used in the first *and* second triangles.

Input: 51125
Output: 0
Because of rule 5, you cannot use `.5`, `1`, and `1.25`. An integer is required before `.5` for it to work.

Input: 051125
Output: 0
Unlike the previous example, there *is* a number before the first `5`, so it is now legal to use `0.5`, `1`, and `1.25`.

Input: 121418439
Output: 2
The numbers `12` and `14` would form a right triangle where side `c` has a length of approximately `18.43908891458577462000`. Because long decimals are truncated to the third digit after the decimal point, we would be left with `18.439`. This fits in with the original input, `121418439`. Additionally, `1.2`, `1.4`, and `1.843` counts as a separate combination, thus giving us our second right triangle.

Input: 10011005
Output: 8
Numbers count separately if they're represented in different ways, so this allows for (1, 00, 1), (1.0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 01), (1, 0.01, 1), (1, 0.01, 1.0), (1, 0.01, 1.00), (1.0, 0.1, 1.005), and (1, 00.1, 1.005).

---

This is code golf, so shortest answer in bytes wins. Good luck!

Comment: Great challenge!  Since this is tagged as [tag:code-golf], could you add the winning criteria?

Comment: Input: 051125, Output: 0?

Comment: but "Unlike the previous example, there is a number before the first 5, so it is now legal to use 0.5, 1, and 1.25."????

Comment: @Tau from what I understood, shortest program in bytes is always the winner for code golf. But I'll edit to mention that explicitly.

Comment: @ASCII-only my mistake. Yes, that would output 1. (I'm not very good at this challenge myself...)

Comment: 1. Should `10011005` yield `1` or `2` (i.e. `1.0, 0.1, 1.005` and `1, 00.1, 1.005`)? 2. Should `101` yield 1 even though the area is `0` (i.e. `1, 0, 1`) or must we special-case ignore such "triangles"?

Comment: 3. Should `15545155452199` yield `0` or `1` (i.e. `1.5545` rounds to `1.555` so `1.555, 1.555, 2.199`) or do we only round a calculated c?

Comment: @JonathanAllan 1. this would output 2 because numbers can be used multiple times, even if they have the same value. 2. Yes, this would output 1. It doesn't matter if the value is zero or not. 3. This would also output 1 because decimals are always rounded to the third decimal place.

Comment: @JonathanAllan the rounding you’ve used here is inconsistent with the example used in the question. (1.2345 to 1.234). Pikachu, what rounding rule should be used? Truncation? Rounding 0.xxx5 to even? Rounding 0.xxx5 up?

Comment: And do we round a and b and then round the square root of the sum of squares again?

Comment: 121418439 has two solutions. 1.2, 1.4, 1.8439 also works.

Comment: With my (3) I was asking the same as Nick has, "And do we round a and b and then round the square root of the sum of squares again?"

Comment: Do all of the numbers have to be used? Would 3450 give one right triangle since 3,4,5.0 works, or two since you could also have 3,4,5 and discard the last digit? The example 345567507 is said to give two right triangles, but if for example it was 34556750 would this be 1 or zero? What about 34510011005? Would that be three triangles (3,4,5 and the two possible for 10011005) or four (effectively 3,4,5 and 1.0, 0.1, 1.005 plus 3,4,5 and 1, 00.1, 1.005)? I think the problem might be better without the possibility of multiple overlapping prefixes/suffixes. It needs clarification anyway.

Comment: If you keep the option for overlapping prefixes/suffixes, there are 8 possibilities for `10011005`: `1, 00, 1`; `1.0, 0, 1`; `1, 0, 01`; `1, 0.01, 1`; `1, 0.01, 1.0`; `1, 0.01, 1.00`; `1.0, 0.1, 1.005`; `1, 00.1, 1.005`. If you use the Cartesian product of prefixes and suffixes there are 12 possible combinations.

Comment: I think this would be a lot simpler and easier to define without the decimals